# Phonegap: Techniques to avoid Apple rejection because of data storage

Tags: cordova, local-storage, fileapi

My plan is to develop an App which allows me to store data locally for offline use.
I know there will be some data which do not need to be persisted since i can load the again.
But there will be data i need to store for long term.
But iam concerned since i see many people getting into trouble with getting their app approved for iOs.

Unfortunately the phonegap documentation does not tell where exactly localStorage is stored and how the FileAPI really works on the internal memory (or even SD).

For example i plan to store user generated data into some folder which is then backed up by itunes/icloud. But then i also have data i simply want to store on the device permanently without being backed up. How can i control this with the localStorage and FileAPI from Phonegap? The FileAPI only gives me the TEMP and PERSISTENT options for the LocalFileSystem class. But what does that mean for Android and iOS, where is my file stored when i use it?

I think to keep my user generated data backed up, i need to get it saved into Documents folder on ios and probably the /Android/data/[package] folder on android. And the rest needs to be put in Cache folder on ios but where do i tell my FileAPI that this file needs to go to Cache or Documents folder?

Does any know how this actually works as the documentation doesn't really tell.